# Obtaing the ROI in Visual basic errors in code after conversion from C

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I've been working on obtaining the ROI of an image, I'm trying to get a square shaped box that will hoover around the region an be able to click and get the standard deviation. I'm familiar with c so i used the c to VB converter, but im getting errors that the statement is not valid in namespace. Everything seems to compatible to VB code. I will be grateful for any suggestions on this matter. Thanks

```
Private Function DrawRoi(Image As Bitmap, rect As RectangleF) As oid
Dim roi As New Rectangle()

roi.X = CInt(CSng(Image.Width) * rect.X)
roi.Y = CInt(CSng(Image.Height) * rect.Y)
roi.Width = CInt(CSng(Image.Width) * rect.Width)
roi.Height = CInt(CSng(Image.Height) * rect.Height)

Dim timer As New Stopwatch()
timer.Start()
' graphics manipulation takes about 240ms on 1080p image
Using roiMaskImage As Bitmap = CreateRoiMaskImage(ImageWithRoi.Width, ImageWithRoi.Height, roi)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ImageWithRoi)
        g.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0)
        g.DrawImage(roiMaskImage, 0, 0)
        Dim borderPen As Pen = CreateRoiBorderPen(ImageWithRoi)
        g.DrawRectangle(borderPen, roi)
    End Using
End Using
Debug.WriteLine("roi graphics: {0}ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
Me.imagePictureBox.Image = ImageWithRoi
End Function

Private Function CreateRoiMaskImage(width As Integer, height As Integer, roi As Rectangle) As Bitmap
Dim image As New Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
    Dim dimBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 0, 0, 0))
    g.FillRectangle(dimBrush, 0, 0, width, height)
    Dim roiBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    g.FillRectangle(roiBrush, roi)
    image.MakeTransparent(Color.Red)
    Return image
End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Which line(s) are giving you the errors? What is the *exact* error message you're getting? This looks like VB6 code, and your tag is for `vb.net`; they're not the same thing, and code is not directly usable between them.

Comment: @KenWhite: This is VB.NET code.

Comment: @HardCode: Thanks. It looked VB6ish to me, but I wasn't positive (which is why I said "looks like" and not "is"). :-) The questions remain, though.

Comment: The give-away is the Using statement ;-)